# How to make a deep type guard?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have the following type:

```js
type Child = {
  foo: number | null
}

type Parent = { 
  child: Child | null
}
```

I want to make a type-guard that receives `Parent` as a parameter and determines if `foo` is a number... something like:

```js
const guard = (parent: Parent): parent?.child?.foo is number => {
  return isNumber(parent?.child?.foo)
}
```

I want TS to be able to now infer that `parent.child` is not null - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to spell it out, e.g.:

```typescript
const guard = (parent: Parent): parent is {child: {foo: number}} => {
    return isNumber(parent?.child?.foo);
};
```

You can do that with intersection types, like this:

```typescript
const guard = (parent: Parent): parent is Parent & {child: Child & {foo: number;};} => {
    return isNumber(parent?.child?.foo);
};
```

(You can always define a type for it rather than an inline intersection.)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAcgVwLYCMCmAnGBeGACgA8AuGAQzAE8BKfAPhimoAdMQAzGY-PAgERg0WbAIDcAKEkt2MAMIALOABsAJvhgBvSTD0xOIEOWEYcMAD4xhKlVIC+UmW0wwAChWyYwsAlpi6+nrAyurkSqoaVjZ2ko7SoJCwAObInhoEhKye3lDkHl4+tOTZhbAI7jk+MABk2iGR4aEadVqGxtYiOOKO9ozagXpeUMjYYPBIXdhZVVAA-AB0DeqL7bQOTmqYwCo5MCqYsKz5s05w3ISp6Vm09DpBiRAgBwsqIMlZS80Law5AA)