# Why does narrowing the type of a child property not remove undefined/null from parent object's type?

Tags: typescript

I want to know why this code behaves as it does, and how to fix it, if possible:

```js
interface Optional {
    opt?: string
}

function isNullOrUndefined<T>(val: T | null | undefined): val is null | undefined {
    return val === null || val === undefined;
}

const x: Optional | undefined = Math.random() > 0.5 ? undefined : { opt: 'hoho' };

if (!isNullOrUndefined(x?.opt)) {
    const y: string = x.opt // Error, even though it should be clear that x is defined
}

if (!isNullOrUndefined(x?.opt)) {
    const y: string = x!.opt // No error, TS knows that child exists. So parent must also exist!
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYjgG2QG8AoZc5bTAfgC5kBnMKUAcxIF8SSYBXEBFlzJgDAHK98+VFACqIACYQYoCAoA8AFQB8ACgBuBepuQAfZCEmFz-JSpBqAlPUOFRFq2eS3lqhcTIKKAgwXigQZFdkAF5YjykzcyjY6O9FXwcFAG5ObgRcJmQAD3oMITxrNLs-GOQAWTgwAAsAOig4RWwAW11HZG1kAAYWgFZkaiqMtWR6IkpMegByJuwVxeQOHJJgGGRdAEJRCSkZeWrM3SLqFqowRz7SCmR8kEKAT3omFhBWWqKbzDIAD0QOQAFEoFBsFAADTICD6CARZrYXisJoiMCMFaSfwAIxQCHwEDgUGQzUaxREDGQ5zUuW2uwORysp3S9jUl2ut3uASeL3en2YbD++wBWJByDE2HhkOhcM0AGVkABrEDYADuNIpWIQTWA+H8ECKojADBayEVMvQpKRWK6vEKBAYMuNpv2nCAA)

Similar questions have already been answered (unsatisfactorily) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255171/how-to-make-typescript-narrow-the-type-of-the-parent-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824941/how-to-make-a-deep-type-guard). In both cases, the answer requires exact knowledge of the type to be checked, which is not helpful.

I suspect that this cannot be done better at the moment (TS 4.8.4). If so, is that a design decision or a shortcoming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: that's a design limitation.

You can read about this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31755#issuecomment-498669080) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506#issuecomment-474802840).

You need to narrow the parent object also, narrowing parents based on properties is done only on special cases.

In your case a simple fix would be something like this:

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(x) && !isNullOrUndefined(x?.opt)) {
    const y: string = x.opt
}
```

Note:
This -

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(x?.opt)) {
    const y: string = x!.opt // No error, TS knows that child exists. So parent must also exist!
}
```

You are just forcing `TS` to believe that `x` is not undefined. The type for `foo` is checked via the type guard. That's the reason it works.

Comment: I got there first on this one big man!

Comment: I'm accepting this because it is the only true answer to my question: That it is a design limitation. And it cites satisfactory sources. Thanks Radu Dita!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to narrow type of x:

Fix:

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined' && !isNullOrUndefined(x.opt)) {
    const y: string = x.opt
}
```

Breakdown of Fix:

```
if (typeof x !== 'undefined' && x.opt !== null && typeof x.opt !== 'undefined') {
    const z: string = x.opt
}
```

On your second point:

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(x?.opt)) {
    const y: string = x!.opt // No error, TS knows that child exists. So parent must also exist!
}
```

You are using the ! operator which I believe tells TypeScript to trust you that it will be defined, which is effectively skipping undefined check. We only use that in special cases, I wouldn't use it here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use generic parameter `T` in the narrowing function (`isNullOrUndefined`) which is a custom type guard. You want to pass a parameter with `any` type to only guarantee that this type is `null` or `undefined`.
Therefore, this can be written more simply and solve the problem in this way:

```
function isNullOrUndefined(val: any): val is null | undefined {
    return val === null || val === undefined;
}
```

Then `x` type is `Optional` in the if block:

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(x)) {
    const y: string = x.opt;   //x type is Optional
}
```

But there is still a problem. You defined the `opt` type as a union of `string` and `undefined`, and you want to assign it to `y` which is a `string` type. This causes an error and can be solved by doing one of these two things.

1- Remove `opt` being optional

```
interface Optional {
    opt: string
}
```

2- Put a runtime javascript checker condition that guarantees that if the value of `opt` is `undefined`, put an **empty string** in `y`

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(x)) {
    const y: string = x.opt || "";
}
```